# Unwrapping creates barrier for Value types

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

Looking at the following code (playground ready).

I'm unable to append data to an unwrapped optional array from within an `if let` statement.

What's the best method to allow appending for an optional array?

```
class ValueTypeTest {
    var data: [Int]?

    func tryAppend() {
        if var unwrappedData = self.data {
            unwrappedData += [2, 3] // problem !
            self.data! += [4, 5]    // works
        } else {
            // Initialize paging and initial results
            self.data = [0, 1]
        }

    }
}

var v = ValueTypeTest()
v.data // nil
v.tryAppend()
v.data // [0, 1]
v.tryAppend()
v.data // expected: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] actual: [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It seems like your design is wrong. A `tryAppend()` operation which always succeeds seems to contradict the idea that the array is optional. I'm sure your example is a simplified one, and may not exhibit some details of your actual code, but in the example you provide an empty non-optional array seems obviously more appropriate than an optional one.

Answer (score 1):

Because Array is a **value** type and will be copied when you do the `if var` operation. So you're not changing `self.data` but `unwrappedData`.

Try this:

```
self.data = (self.data ?? [0, 1]) + [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

This is what I mean.

```
func tryAppend() {
    if let unwrappedData = self.data {
        self.data = unwrappedData + [2, 3, 4, 5]
    } else {
        // Initialize paging and initial results
        self.data = [0, 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but assigning to self.data beats the purpose of the unwrapping. I agree it's a better syntax I just wonder if this is the recommended solution.

Comment: @MaximVeksler Well, at least you can do `self.data = unwrappedData  + [2, 3]`. This might better suit your purpose? If you think about it, this is pretty much what you can do when unwrapping a value type.

Comment: tend to agree. Please update your answer? I'll see if this makes sense and accept.

Comment: @MaximVeksler Updated.

Answer (score 0):

`var unwrappedData` declared inside the function `tryAppend()` is a local variable for that function.

The result pane at that line shows you the output containing: `[0, 1, 2, 3]` for `unwrappedData`.